# How to estimate the value of this absolute sum?

Tags: complex-analysis, summation, products, estimation

(*) $\quad$ $\hspace{1mm} |\sum_{k=0}^{N}(\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(\frac{n-i}{n}) - 1)\frac{z^{k}}{k!}| \hspace{1mm}$

Consider (*) for some bounded $N < n$.

I want to confirm that (*) is bounded by some $\epsilon > 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I don´t know how to estimate this expression (*).
I have observed that the product $\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(\frac{n-i}{n})$ is close to one as $n \rightarrow \infty$. But how to claim that this is enough for the sum to be bounded by some $\epsilon$?

I mean according to the exercise we have: $\hspace{1mm} |\sum_{k=0}^{N}(\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(\frac{n-i}{n}) - 1)\frac{z^{k}}{k!}| \leq \sum_{k=0}^{N}|\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(\frac{n-i}{n}) - 1|\frac{|z|^{k}}{k!} < \dots < \epsilon$

But how to confirm that since $|\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(\frac{n-i}{n}) - 1|$ tends to 1 in the limit.

I have also tried to find a pattern by looking at $k = 0,1,2,3,\dots$

$k=0 \Rightarrow (*) = 0$

$k=1 \Rightarrow (*) = 0$

$k=2 \Rightarrow (*) = \frac{1}{2!n}|z|^{2}$

$k=3 \Rightarrow (*) = \frac{3n-2}{3!n^{2}} |z|^{3}$

$k=4 \Rightarrow (*) = \frac{6n^{2}-11n-6}{4!n^{3}} |z|^{4}$

But I don´t recognize a pattern in the numerators $0, 0, 1, 3n-2, 6n^{2}-11n-6$.

Comment: Not sure what you ask as $|\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(\frac{n-i}{n}) - 1| \le 2$ so the sum is at most $2e^{|z|}$

Comment: As $n-i \leq n$ for all $i \geq 0$, $\frac{n-i}{n} \leq 1$ for all such i. Hence the product over $\frac{n-i}{n}$ is less or equal than 1. And the product is bigger or equal to zero, since all those terms in the product are nonnegative. Hence $|\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (\frac{n-i}{n}) - 1| \leq 1$. But my claim is now that the product will converge to 1 as $n -> \infty$. But I don´t know how to proof/confirm that.